# Resolve screen rotation image on Olympus E-PL5

Tags: olympus, rear-lcd

My Olympus PEN Lite E-PL5 has an LCD screen which can be tilted up, and flipped over for selfies. When it's fully upright the screen flips. When you fold the screen back down, the orientation restores. Today, I flipped the screen up to take a selfie with the family, and when the screen was returned to its normal orientation, the screen remains upside down.

Is there a way to reset the gyro in the device, so it's aware of its orientation? Or, do I need to factory reset? In which case, how do I do this? The `Reset/Myset` menu option is disabled, and I can't find any other factory reset options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly an answer, but upgrading the firmware from v1.3 to v1.6 seems to have done the trick. I orientated the screen up, folded it back down and the LCD image has returned to normal.

Update - the issue has returned, so I've upgraded to an OM-D E-M10 Mark III.